# How to select multiple values from Picker component in react-native?

Tags: react-native, picker

`react-native` `Picker` component doesn't seem like providing `multiselect` option https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html#enabled

But, I have com across some libraries which provides `multiselect` option like,

https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multiple-select-list

But is there any way to select multiple values without going for package?

Comment: You can always write your own, but those packages were written to provide functionality on top of the FB library. Why would you not want to use one?

Comment: If you just don't like `npm i`, copy package to your own folder ex: `./src/myfolder/react-native-multiple-select-list` then you can `import MultiPicker from './src/myfolder/react-native-multiple-select-list'` from there.

Comment: @Adam Kipnis, Thank you.

Comment: @Val, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Adam Kipnis pointed out, you could always write your own.

You can store the values in an array and render from there.

Since the question was asked the developer team has deprecated the default Picker component. They provide a link for community packages.
https://reactnative.directory/?search=picker